# How to automatically create Note record in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I've noticed that whenever an AR Invoice gets saved, a record gets created in the Note table with the new invoice's note ID. Can you tell me how that is being accomplished? I'd like to get one of my screens to do the same thing. I guess there must be some kind of attribute on the either the DAC or the graph but I can't find it. I have the PXNote attribute on the NoteID column in my DAC but it does not cause a Note record to be automatically created.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have Note record automatically created when a new parent record gets saved, one should invoke the static `PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID<Field>(PXCache cache, object data)` method when the parent record is inserted in the cache.

For example, to have Note record automatically created when a new Stock Item gets saved, you should subscribe to RowInserted handler for the InventoryItem DAC and call `PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID<Field>(...)`:

```
public class InventoryItemMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{
    public void InventoryItem_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        var noteCache = Base.Caches[typeof(Note)];
        var oldDirty = noteCache.IsDirty;
        PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID<InventoryItem.noteID>(sender, e.Row);
        noteCache.IsDirty = oldDirty;
    }
}
```

The code snippet above can be incorporated into almost any custom BLC with a couple simple changes to replace InventoryItem with a custom DAC.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan! This assisted me in linking a CRActivity to a custom DAC item.

Comment: Could this be done with NoteDoc as well so I can generate a FileID for a newly inserted object and upload a file to it during its insertion?

Comment: Nope, files can only be attached to an already saved in the database record.